# Projection is linear

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove:
the orthogonal projection is linear.

Definition :
Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $H$, $H$ be a hilbert space. We define the orthogonal projection $P_M$ in $H$ on $M$ as:
$||P_Mx-x||:=min_{m \in M} ||m-x||$

I want to show that $P_M$ as defined above is linear.

I already know that $(x-P_Mx) \perp M$ for every $m \in M$ and that $P_Mx$ is the unique Element of $M$, such that this holds.

So let $x,y \in H$, then I can write
$P_M(x+y)=<(x+y)-(P_Mx+P_My),m>=<x-P_Mx,m>+<y-P_My,m>=P_M(x)+P_M(y)$

Now I am not really sure how to show $P_M(\lambda x)=\lambda P_M(x)$.
I tried writing it again as
$P_M(\lambda x)=<\lambda x-P_M\lambda x,m>$

But I don't know how to argue that $<\lambda x-P_M\lambda x,m>=<\lambda x-\lambda P_M x,m>$.

Comment: Since $M$ is a closed subspace, for $\lambda \neq 0$ we have $\min_{m\in M} \Vert m - x \Vert = \min_{m\in M} \Vert \frac{m}{\lambda} - x \Vert$.

Comment: @stange Do you mean $min_{m \in M} ||m - \lambda x||=|\lambda| min_{m \in M}||\frac{m}{\lambda}-x||$?

Comment: Since $\lambda x \in M$, we get $<\lambda x -P_M   \lambda x,m>=0$, and $<\lambda x -\lambda P_M  x,m>= \lambda <x-P_Mx,m>=0$.

Comment: @Peter thank you, I think I got it